# facebook APP automatic login

Tags: php, facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

I have made a facebook app, but I am unsure I have understood something correctly.

I have been working with alot of code, trying to get this window: [Image example](http://i50.tinypic.com/wb6stk.png)

But now I have been puzzling with this under my app settings [my settings](http://i48.tinypic.com/24lrgw2.png)

I have submitted all my data, but when I enter the app as a tester, I don't get this window dialog.

Maybe it is something to do with under "App details". Since it is only on test stage, I havn't pressed "Submit App Detail Page" yet.

Can anyone clear this area for me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have submitted all my data, but when I enter the app as a tester, I don't get this window dialog.

These setting are for users coming to your app from within the app center only. (They used to be for Authenticated Referrals as well, but those are deprecated and should not be used any more in new apps.)

But whenever the user reaches your app by other means (page tab on a Facebook page, canvas app), you have to trigger login yourself and specify the permissions while doing so with the `scope` parameter.

Please familiarize yourself with the basics of building apps on the platform and the mechanisms of authentication:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I will look into it and maybe accept this as an answer :)

Comment: I added some php login code to my app, so I got the login screen

Answer (score 1):

just to add to what CBroe said, as facebook announced, on the following list, they're going to deprecate "Authenticated referrals" (which is in app permission tab) on February 6th, 2013. So don't use authenticated referrals and authenticate the user via the code (js-sdk or php-sdk etc)

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/11/07/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

Comment: I mean who doesn't?! they won the worst api prize! lol
http://techcrunch.com/2011/08/11/facebook-wins-worst-api-in-developer-survey/